# Calling PHP object attribute name from variable

Tags: php, variables

There is a session variable called 'locale' with value: en.

```
$locale = session()->get('locale'); // value = 'en';
```

And there is an object `$page` with attributes: `content_en`, `content_ru`, `content_de`.

All I need is to echo `$page->content_en` or `$page->content_ru` or `$page->content_de`, but depending on locale.

```
echo $page->content_'.session()->get('locale').';
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more complete solution that you can even run on phpfiddle.org

```
$page = new stdClass();
$page->content_en = 'Testcontent';
$page->content_de = 'Testinhalt';

$property = 'content_' . locale("en");

if(property_exists($page, $property)) {
    // The property exists, print it!
    echo $page->$property;
} else {
    // Fallback to some default
}


function locale($loc)
{
    return $loc;
}
```

Comment: It does, but has not been requested. If it's needed, I'll add it

Comment: I suggest you add it to your answer. Some people might not recognize that this is required.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fabian's answer is more flexible and generally better. However, here's an alternative approach **if you only accept specific values**.

#### Using `if`

```
$locale = session()->get('locale'); // value = 'en';

if ($locale == "en") {
  echo $page->content_en;
} elseif ($locale == "ru") {
  echo $page->content_ru;
} elseif ($locale == "de") {
  echo $page->content_de;
}
```

#### Using `switch`

```
$locale = session()->get('locale'); // value = 'en';

switch ($locale) {
  case "en":
    echo $page->content_en;
    break;
  case "ru":
    echo $page->content_ru;
    break;
  case "de":
    echo $page->content_de;
    break;
}
```

Comment: And this approach will only work for property names known at the time of implementation. Not for dynamically created objects.

Comment: @arkascha Correct. Fabians answer is better for that purpose. This is just an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access a property via a combined string.
The only option you have is to first put it in a string, and use that variable as a property access.

```
$property = 'content_' . session()->get('locale');
if( isset($page->$property) ) {
    echo $page->$property;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
echo $page->{'content_' . session()->get('locale')};
```